# Remove content from before element CSS

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

How can i remove this '`content`' programmatically using Jquery ?

```
body:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-right: -0.25em;
}
```

Comment: You can't manipulate CSS pseudo elements using JavaScript as they are not technically part of the DOM.

Comment: i can i remove this using css ?

Comment: `body:before { display: none; }`

Comment: Do you just want to remove the `:before` element?

Comment: yes, it can be a solution

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to directly access psuedo elements in jQuery because they are not part of the DOM.

However as a workaround, you could base the psuedo element on a class on the body, eg:

```
body:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-right: -0.25em;
}
body.foo:before { 
    display: none;
}
```

Then to hide the element in jQuery:

```
$('body').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: here is a fiddle the pseudo element is removed on the click event on body : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6h5awgky/

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks. I added some content to the psuedo element to make it more obvious what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/6h5awgky/1/

Comment: Nice. I like this alot.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite it:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('body:before', 'display: none !important;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can modify `body:before`'s `display` property and set it to `none`.

Inspect Element to see the modified rule.

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "body:before") {
      console.log('Before: ' + r.cssText);
      r.style.display = 'none';
      console.log('After: ' + r.cssText);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
```